# Uncaught ReferenceError on Svelte writable array

Tags: svelte-3

I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: $writableArray is not defined at addFoo

arrays.js:

```
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
export const writableArray = writable([])
```

stores.js:

```
import {writableArray} from './arrays.js'
import {subscribe} from 'svelte/internal'
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

export const addFoo = (bar) => {
  $writableArray = [...$writableArray, {
    bar: bar,
    datetime: Date.now()
  }];
};

export const foos = addFoo() // this is so that I can have a readable store too
```

I based my code on [Svelte example](https://svelte.dev/repl/a551a40e90374fd2861255c957123af2?version=3.22.2)

Comment: Do you have a component showing how you're trying to access it? It seems maybe you're trying to import `$writableArray` from `stores.js` which will not work since `arrays.js` exports that variable. Your code works if stores are imported from the right files. https://svelte.dev/repl/951a6460c4dd45199256e0c4c06df391?version=3.22.2

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `$store` syntax in `.js` file.
Instead use the normal `update` function:

```js
writableArray.update(oldArray => [...oldArray, { newObject }])
```